# How to generate a fake but valid protocol hash?

Tags: protocol

How do I generate a fake but valid protocol hash, like `ProtoGenesisGenesisGenesisGenesisGenesisGenesk612im`?

Comment: i think you might as well simply ask the more general question: "how is the protocol hash computed" because it has never been explained here in detail. From there you should be able to try generate vanity protocols hashes if you like ;)

Comment: I think a "real" protocol hash, like `PsddFKi32cMJ2qPjf43Qv5GDWLDPZb3T3bF6fLKiF5HtvHNU7aP` is just the `b58_check` encoding of the hash of the source code of some economic protocol (like the contents of the directory `src/proto_003_PsddFKi3/lib_protocol/src` in `https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/tree/mainnet`). However, I think a "fake hash", like `ProtoALphaALphaALphaALphaALphaALphaALphaALphaDdp3zK`, is not the hash of something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A "Tezos protocol hash" like `PsqEZzKWvmWY29kV6oJZhWDNz9FMmYDjV3S7c496zMuAGDYAF7e` is the Base58Check encoding of the hash of some protocol code.

The Base58Check encoding of some data is obtained as follows:

```
  base58encode(prefix + data + checksum)
```

where `prefix` is some fixed bytestring used to identify the type of data we are encoding, `data` is the bytestring we are encoding, and `checksum` are the last 4 bytes of `SHA256(SHA256(prefix+data))` (and `+` is bytestring concatenation).

For a "real" protocol hash, `data` is the Blake2B hash (on 32 bytes) of the protocol code, and `prefix` is chosen such that the Base58Check encoding starts with the letter `P`. It turns out that this prefix is `"\002\170"` (`"\x02\xaa"`), see the `Prefix` submodule of the [`Base58` module](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/master/src/lib_crypto/base58.ml).

A "fake" protocol hash is such that it does not represent any protocol code, instead it is just a valid Base58Check string. So `data` is the empty bytestring, and what we want is to find the bytestring `prefix` such the encoding starts with some meaningful target prefix like `ProtoGenesisGenesisGenesisGenesisGenesisGenes`. To this end the Python script [b58_prefix.py](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/master/scripts/b58_prefix/b58_prefix.py) comes to the rescue:

```
$ scripts/b58_prefix.py ProtoGenesisGenesisGenesisGenesisGenesisGenes 0
51 78975543388164909405054148723984031781676975010405372310033317301022658928601531 [2L, 170L, 11L, 205L, 127L, 252L, 160L, 63L, 87L, 227L, 132L, 83L, 240L, 211L, 232L, 76L, 48L, 36L, 3L, 192L, 83L, 87L, 68L, 139L, 76L, 45L, 174L, 248L, 179L, 168L, 190L, 60L, 105L, 187L]
```

We invoke it with the desired target prefix and the length of the payload (this is `0` as the payload is empty). The list represents the desired `prefix`. Finally, we just need to encode this prefix:

```
import base58

def tb(l):
    return b''.join(map(lambda x: x.to_bytes(1, 'big'), l))

res = base58.b58encode_check(tb([2, 170, 11, 205, 127, 252, 160, 63, 87, 227, 132, 83, 240, 211, 232, 76, 48, 36, 3, 192, 83, 87, 68, 139, 76, 45, 174, 248, 179, 168, 190, 60, 105, 187]))

print(res)
```

which gives us: `b'ProtoGenesisGenesisGenesisGenesisGenesisGenes3pWKfA'`.

Answer (score 7):

1. Take `blake2b` hash of arbitrary data.
2. Prepend `\x02\xaa` and base58 encode it with checksum.

Example in Python:

```
from pytezos.encoding import base58_encode
from pytezos.crypto import blake2b_32

base58_encode(blake2b_32('test').digest(), b'P')
>>> b'PsqEZzKWvmWY29kV6oJZhWDNz9FMmYDjV3S7c496zMuAGDYAF7e'
```